# I need to extract the prefix, number, and option suffix from a highway number

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a program in C# that processes highway designation in the general form:

{1-2 chars}{1-3 digits}[1-4 chars]

For example:

- I70
- I70BR
- US550
- US550Trk

What might be the regular expression to match this input and store the prefix (eg., I or US), the number (eg., 70 or 550), and the optional suffix (eg., BR, or Trk) in an array of matches.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: This is really basic stuff - can you really not just read the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you need is as follows:

```
^([A-Za-z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})([A-Za-z]{0,4})$
```

You've said that the last group is between 1 and 4 characters, however you stated that it's optional in the same question. I went with the latter option, because not all the input that you provided had a suffix.

Sample usage:

```
var input = "US550Trk";
var pattern = @"^([A-Za-z]{1,2})(\d{1,3})([A-Za-z]{0,4})$";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var results = regex.Match(input).Groups.
    OfType<Group>().
    Skip(1).
    Select(g => g.Value).
    ToArray();
```

The `Skip(1)` is there because the first group always contains the whole match.